# How to get Junit class name in another class

Tags: java, junit4, cucumber-jvm

Below is a JUnit Runner from which I need to get class name **RunTest** in another class.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = { "src/test/resources/features/Automated" },
        tags = { "@Create_Account_Without_Entering_Mandatory_Fields", "~@ToBeSkipped","~@P2" }
        , dryRun = false,

        monochrome = true,
        glue = "tv.nativ.mio.automation.stepdef", plugin = {"html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber/cucumber1.json"})

public class RunTest  {
}
```

I have tried `Thread.dumpStack()` and `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` but not getting class `RunTest` in the list

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend that, but you can remember the test class in some static variable. Do in the test:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() {
    // holder is just a class with static variable, create it
    CurrentClassHolder.setClass(RunTest.class);
}
```

You can do such thing in every test class and then get it from there..